# Handlers delegation in polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

**UPDATE**: The response and error events no longer bubble. https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/releases/tag/v1.0.5
what a pity.

Original question:

I wanted to create custom ajax component based on iron-ajax to add couple of custom headers and handlers. While custom element inheritance is not yet implemented I just added iron-ajax to my-ajax and was going to delegate all api to the iron-ajax, this worked fine with generateRequest.

But when it got to handler methods I noticed that it works without any delegation. There is no on-response handler defined in my-ajax elt but handleResponse is still invoked.

As far as I understand, this happens because Polymer.Base._addFeature._createEventHandler (polymer.html:345)
uses 'this', which is top-level elt, as 'host' for handler methods definitions.

So the question is: is it bug or feature?

The example code:

```html
<link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/master/iron-ajax.html">

<dom-module id="my-ajax">
    <template>
         <iron-ajax
                id="ironAjax"
                url="http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/otherkey/othervalue"
                handle-as="json"
                debounce-duration="300"
                >
        </iron-ajax>
    </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-ajax",
      
        generateRequest: function(){
             this.$.ironAjax.generateRequest();
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="my-elt">
  <template>
    <button on-click="buttonClick">Button</button>
    <my-ajax
              id="myAjax" 
              on-response="handleResponse">
        </my-ajax>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-elt",
        buttonClick: function(){
          this.$.myAjax.generateRequest();
        },
        handleResponse: function(event) {
          alert('got response');
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>


<my-elt></my-elt>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most events bubble, so you are just seeing the `response` event bubble out of `my-ajax` to the `my-elt` scope via the handler placed on the `my-ajax` instance.  This happens identically to a `click` event bubbling from a lower scope to an upper scope.

So answer is: "feature" (of the web platform, more than Polymer itself).

Comment: hmmm... maybe even bubles from iron-ajax to my-ajax? But why then my-ajax thinks it should hanle it? It has no on-response handlers defined. I'd expect it to throw error when encountering unexpected attribute, or, well, since it's html, at leat warning.

Comment: or, does adding "on-eventname" attribute to any element make it capable of handling such events?